# Css fixed column amount regardless of children count without FlexBox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, weasyprint

Basically, I want to replicate the `col-6` (or `col-x`) behavior of `Bootstrap` without using `FlexBox`.

A div that all its children are paired and wrapped, and when once it removed, it rearranges itself.

For example, if I remove `Child 2`:

```
--------------------------------
| Child 1 with |               |
|  Very long   |    Child 2    |
|    Text      |               |
--------------------------------
|   Child 3    |    Child 4    |
--------------------------------
```

This should happen :

```
--------------------------------
| Child 1 with |               |
|  Very long   |    Child 3    |
|    Text      |               |
--------------------------------
|   Child 4    |
----------------
```

It's important that it works with elements of different heights!

I'm not sure what kind of code sample I can post here, I know how to do this using FlexBox but I can't use it as I'm using a PDF creating a library that doesn't fully support FlexBox, so I'm trying different approaches until I replicate what I need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can also just use Bootstrap 3, which doesn't include Flexbox

Comment: @Helenesh well I tried using display:table and display:table-cell, but that doesn't wrap the elements

Comment: either just make your inner elements inline-block or float them left and they should naturally line up line that

Comment: @Pete I just tried that, but it didn't work with elements of different heights/lengths

Comment: it would if you use inline block with vertical align bottom on them

Comment: @Pete it did work! Except I had to set the width to 49% instead of 50%, did I miss anything? Mind posting a sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: @Pete thanks that did work, another minor issue is that "orphan" element (alone in a row) get centered instead of in the left as my sketch, is there a way to have a selector for these elements? Kinda like a `if odd number of children` selector

Comment: just put text align left on parent - if you need the text inside each box centred, put the centring on the box, not the parent.  It's not rocket science.  And this is why you need to create a [mcve] so you don't end up asking fifty questions to what should be a very simple question

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a non flexbox based framework like bootstrap 3 or skeleton. however if you just want what you have described in the question then you can just use display inline-block.

```css
.box {
 height:50px;
 background: indianred;
 width:48%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.box1 {
 background: indianred;
}
.box2 {
 background: steelblue;
}
.box3 {
 background: coral;
}
.box4 {
 background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1">BOX 1</div>
<div class="box box2">BOX 2</div>
<div class="box box3">BOX 3</div>
<div class="box box4">BOX 4</div>

<hr>

<div class="box box1">BOX 1</div>
<!-- <div class="box box2">BOX 2</div> -->
<div class="box box3">BOX 3</div>
<div class="box box4">BOX 4</div>
```

Comment: I know I didn't specify this, but this doesn't work if one box has a very long text